# Control multiple parameter with dashes in url

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.0 framework and I have a route like this:

www.example.com/title-size

Where size is an optional parameter

```
Route::any('embed-{title}-{size?}',['uses'=>'Posts@getData','as'=>'embed'])->where('title', '.*(?=-)');
```

Because my title contains dashes so it was ignoring my optional size parameter so I have researched and found this `->where('title', '.*(?=-)');` which is working good. Now the problem comes that I have to allways add size parameter. If no size parameter the route is not working so it gives me a 404.

Comment: Why aren't you using query strings?

Answer (score 1):

Please use Middleware as helper for your route. This is a standard in Laravel 5 and will help you achieve what you are looking for.
Take a look at the basic examples from the /app/Http/Middleware/

Comment: sir would you please solve my problem i don't know how